# Most efficient way to prevent memory hog while loading iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am developing a website where links open in an iFrame. This keeps everything in flow. It works pretty well on computers but on mobile devices it lags a bit specially on chrome. 
When user cliks a link the website is loaded in a modal in iFrame. Is there any way I can make sure that the scrolling is still smooth on mobile devices and speed up the load times of iFrame some how?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

try :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Mobile browsers like render pages in a virtual "window" (the viewport), usually wider than the screen, so they don't need to squeeze every page layout into a tiny window (which would break many non-mobile-optimized sites). Users can pan and zoom to see different areas of the page.

Mobile Safari introduced the "viewport meta tag" to let web developers control the viewport's size and scale.

So your iFrame pages suppose to have the meta tag.